# Handling "Thrown exception type is not nothrow copy constructible" Warning

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, std, clang-tidy

Going back to C++ development after a 12 years hiatus. I'm using JetBrains's CLion software which is great since it provides a lot of input on possible issues on my class design. One of the warning I get in my class' constructor throw statement is: `Thrown exception type is not nothrow copy constructible`. Here is a code sample that generates this warning:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

using std::invalid_argument;
using std::string;

class MyClass {
    public:
        explicit MyClass(string value) throw (invalid_argument);
    private:
        string value;
};

MyClass::MyClass(string value) throw (invalid_argument) {
    if (value.length() == 0) {
        throw invalid_argument("YOLO!"); // Warning is here.
    }

    this->value = value;
}
```

This piece of code compiles and I am able to unit test it. But I would like very much to get rid of this warning (in order to understand what I am doing wrong, even though it compiles).

Comment: Why are you using throw specifications? They have been deprecated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841559/deprecated-throw-list-in-c11

Comment: Pain `throw` specifiers bring. Much pain. Better off without, you are.

Comment: Regardless of the interaction between nothrow copy and exceptions (which I am not expert in), note that the error you are trying to detect is not something that should be handled with an exception. it is basically a usage or logical mistake, you should terminate your program (or detect empty strings are compile time) if you don’t want empty strings as constructor input.

Answer (score 10):

The comment provided by Neil is valid. In C++ 11, using `throw` in a function signature has been deprecated in favor of `noexcept`. In this case, my constructor's signature should have been:

```
explicit MyClass(string value) noexcept(false);
```

But, since `noexcept(false)` is applied by default to all functions, unless `noexcept` or `noexcept(true)` is specified, I can simply use:

```
explicit MyClass(string value);
```

Going back to how to fix the "Thrown exception type is not nothrow copy constructible” warning, I found [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160730024945/https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/ERR60-CPP.+Exception+objects+must+be+nothrow+copy+constructible) that explains very well what the issue is and how to fix it.